# NSScrollView has space at the bottom and scrollbar always at bottom in Cocoa

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa, nsscrollview

I created a NSScrollView and add custom NSVIew in it but when run, it always has a space at bottom and the scroll bar always at bottom. Now, i want to scrollview fit with custom view and scrollbar always at top. This is my code:

```
 float label_Y;
float textfield_Y;
float heightView;
-(void) createTableWiFi: (int) number
{

    heightView = (25 + 30) * number;

    guiView = [[NSView alloc] initWithFrame:NSMakeRect(0,0,600, heightView)];

    label_Y = heightView;
    textfield_Y = heightView ;
    [[ScrollView verticalScroller] setFloatValue:0.0];
    [[ScrollView contentView] scrollToPoint:NSMakePoint(0.0, heightView)];
    int i;
    for(i=1; i<=number;i++)
    {

        ssidtxt = [[NSTextField alloc] initWithFrame:NSMakeRect (50,textfield_Y,130,25)];
        [ssidtxt setBezelStyle:NSTextFieldSquareBezel];
        ssidtxt.tag=i;
        [ssidtxt setAutoresizingMask:NSViewWidthSizable];

        [guiView addSubview:ssidtxt];

        [ssidtxt release];


        keytxt = [[KSPasswordField alloc] initWithFrame:NSMakeRect (200,textfield_Y,130,25)];
        [guiView addSubview:keytxt];
        [keytxt release];

        textfield_Y -=30;
    }
    prototype= [[NSButtonCell alloc] init];
    [prototype setTitle:@""];
    [prototype setButtonType:NSRadioButton];

    NSRect matrixRect = NSMakeRect(500, textfield_Y +25  , 50,25 *(i-1));
    myMatrix = [[NSMatrix alloc] initWithFrame:matrixRect
                                          mode:NSRadioModeMatrix
                                     prototype:(NSCell *)prototype
                                  numberOfRows:i-1
                               numberOfColumns:1];
    [myMatrix setCellSize:NSMakeSize(50, 30)];

    [myMatrix setAction:@selector(radioButtonClicked:)];
    NSArray *cellArray = [myMatrix cells];

    [guiView addSubview:myMatrix];

    [ScrollView  setDocumentView :guiView];
    [[ScrollView verticalScroller] setFloatValue:0.0];
    [[ScrollView contentView] scrollToPoint:NSMakePoint(0.0, heightView)];
    [guiView release];
}
```

Welcome any suggestions. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

Don't do this.

```
[[ScrollView verticalScroller] setFloatValue:0.0];
```

You might be forcing it to cause some inconsistencies. If your scrollbar position is not updating(which I am not quite sure if that is your problem) use

```
[ScrollView reflectScrolledClipView:[ScrollView contentView]];
```

Also please read [Cocoa coding guidelines](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CodingGuidelines/CodingGuidelines.html). Its a relatively short read but very worthwhile.